# Storing data from form using onSubmitted vs onPressed

Tags: flutter

I'm able to enter a data into the database using onSubmit

```
  Expanded _buildAddNameField(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        controller: oneController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
        onSubmitted: (inputName) {
          final database = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context);
          final task = AddCashFlow(
            addName: inputName,
            addAmount: newAddAmount,
          );
          database.insertAddCash(task);
          resetValuesAfterSubmit();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I want to be able to the same thing onPressed

```
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildAddNameField(context),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Update Cash Flow"),
            onPressed: () {
              final database = Provider.of<AppDatabase>(context);
              final task = AddCashFlow(
                addName: inputName,

              );
              database.insertAddCash(task);
              resetValuesAfterSubmit();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

```
  Expanded _buildAddNameField(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextField(
        controller: oneController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but it's coming up as null

How would I use onPressed to enter the value from the textfield into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try rebuilding your project? Hot reload sometimes doesnt work your code is good I dont see any errors

Comment: yes, this is the error I get when I use onSubmitted
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: InvalidDataException: Sorry, AddCashFlow(id: null, addName: null, addAmount: null) cannot be used for that because:

Comment: Because you only passed 1 argument to AddCashFlow were there should be three and I think you didnt passed any default value if there are null values

Comment: Can you send the screenshot of your AddCashFlow method?

Comment: I don't think thats the issue because I can get the data when I use onSubmitted 
`
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: InvalidDataException: Sorry, AddCashFlow(id: null, addName: sample text, addAmount: null) cannot be used for that because:
• addAmount: This value was required, but isn't present
`

Comment: addName: sample text //the data
addAmount: null

Comment: I think inputName in your raised button isnt defined because input name was the text in your textfield thats why it doesnt recognize any texts try putting inputName.toString() Im sure it will return null as string and will work

Comment: Or you can use addName: oneController.text

Comment: Maybe its defined but you didnt set the new value to whatever your textfields value is

Comment: I didnt see any onChanged: (){ setState((){inputName = oneController.text});